# installing rocket chat on freebsd

Tags: npm, freebsd, nave

I am trying to install rocket chat on freebsd 10.

I tried installing using docker (https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat/wiki/Deploy-with-Docker) and I was able install docker but not docker-compose.

Installing it without docker (https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat/wiki/Deploy-Rocket.Chat-without-docker), I get stuck with nave. That is, after

```
npm install nave -g
```

and executing

```
nave usemain 0.5.3
```

i get this response

```
nave: Command not found.
```

Basically I just need Rocket Chat server working on freebsd. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Check location where npm installs its packages and make sure it's added to `PATH`.

Comment: I did that and it's in /usr/local/bin. At least the link is. /usr/local/bin is in my PATH. I also tried executing it directly that is, /usr/local/bin/nave and I still get "Command not found". By the way the link is not broken since I can see the code when i edit /usr/local/bin/nave.

Comment: Check the shebang of this file, then. `cat /usr/local/bin/nave | head`.

Comment: #! is /bin/bash. I installed bash but and saw that bash is in /usr/local/bin/bash so I redirected shebang to that. but now the shell testing part of the script is preventing the rest of the script to execute. it checks $SHELL and it should be equal to bash or zsh. I'm looking into how to change that environment too when I change to bash